# there is a string function to add to the end of a char array while leaving the null terminator in place?

Tags: arrays, c, string, search

i am slightly new at c programing..sorry.

i have to do a project that takes in a directory name from the command line then opens it, reads it, saves all file names into a character array and then i need to make another array that points to the first letter of the file name in the first array.
for example if my directory passed in is p1
and p1 contains files main.c, node.c, and header.h
then the first array should read "main.c/0node.c/0header.h"
and the second array should be secondArray[0]=&FirstArray[0], SecondArray[1]=&FirstArray[7], secondArray[2]=&FirstArray[14]

my questions are 1) is there a function that will allow me to continue writing to FirstArray while leaving the null terminator in there? (i want to put this in a loop so it would just add to the end of firstArray after each readdir())

and 2) is there a simple way to go about the secondArray?
my idea is something like this... but i dont have any clue if this will actually work and i used getnextchar() in this but i dont know if thats actually a thing, but what i mean is i need to check if there is anything after the null terminator to see if the firstArray is actually empty or not.

```
int i=0; //firstArray index
int j=1;//secondArray index
int counter=0 //keep count
secondArray[0]= &FirstArray[0];// set the secondArray[0] before going further
  while((getnextchar(FirstArray))!=NULL){
    while (firstArray[i] != '/0'){
     counter++;
     i++;
     }//end first while
  secondArray[j]=&firstArray[count+1]
  j++;
  }//end second while
```

Comment: The NUL-termination character is the convention for a C string. There is nothing that prevents one from using a `char*`, eg., as something that is _not_ a C string; it just won’t work “correctly” with the calls that work with C strings, either ending too early or not ending early enough.

Comment: Also, `'/0'` is not correct, and should likely raise at least a warning. Make sure to post actual/representative code.

Comment: im sorry, i havent actually written code that works yet thats why i didnt post it, im still trying to figure out how i would write it. would it be "/0"? or just in general that wont work at all?

Comment: It's `'\0'` sloped the other way.